# Wrap 'K in keyof T' with a generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

```
 type CustomFieldWrapper<T> = {
  isDirty: boolean
  value: T
}

type WrappedFormValues<T>> = {
    CustomFieldWrapper< [K in keyof T]: T[K] >
};
```

I would like to make sure that all [K in keyof T]: T[K], are also wrapped with my CustomFieldWrapper

Then I want to be able to

```
var myfield: WrappedFormValues<{ name: string, email: string}> = {
         name: GetCustomFieldWrapper("name", "initial name value"),
         email: GetCustomFieldWrapper("email", "initial email value"),
}
```

Now obviously I cannot use that syntax. CustomFieldWrapper < something > doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:T[K]` is the type annotation for the field in the resulting object. You can put your wrapping type there:

```
type WrappedFormValues<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: CustomFieldWrapper<T[K] >
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgrgZ2AewLYDECWEA2ATAdQCcBDMSIgHgBUA+KAXigG8AoKDqTBAEUyNAAuKACNkyHBBIA7dpwBuJHHAjDqrAL6tWoSFGJlIedMiKoAakpUIa9Jm05QA2gGku0qAGsIIZADMoagBdYXgkNCxcQlJyCCpqVyDaTQBuViA)